# Apache 2.4 Directory access control for mod_auth_form

Tags: directory, apache2, mod-auth

I need some help with this simple directory access rules - sorry I  just started playing with Apache 2.4 and not done this before.

I have configured Apache 2.4 to a stage where I can see a login for for protected resources and once I enter the user/pass I get access to the protected resourced.

Now I want to do the following which I am not sure how I can get this done.

1. Web root is set to /var/www
2. /var/www/login - anyone can access, no auth required as this folder contains login.html and logout.html. ( I got this working)
3. /var/www - all other contents in the root of my app can only be accessed after authentication. This is the part I don't know how to setup.

My vhost conf looks like this.

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ServerName auth-test.ml.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-access_log" common

<Directory "/var/www">
    AuthFormProvider file
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Reserved Area"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    require valid-user

        # This is the login page
    ErrorDocument 401 /login/index.html

    # This is the file containing users login data
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache2/auth/.htpasswd

</Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/login>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

AT the moment when I access the app like http://example.com  I expect to see the login.html page returned but I get the following error message:

```
Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was as simple as using Directory to first deny access to all to the root document and only allow valid users.

Using another Directory to open access to all to the auth folder.